# Getting errorInfo back from tryParse()

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im playing around with TryParse()

But lets say the parsing fails, then returns false, and ... nothing..
Is there a way to get info back about what failed the parsing?

I saw something like that at codeproject, but i didnt really understand it.

Thanks :)

Comment: How do you plan to use that information .. if it was available ?

Comment: I guess tell the user what went wrong, and what he or she got to fix before moving on.

I know it would probably be enough to tell the user that the email was not valid, then he or she probably would be able to see whats wrong..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no way of getting that information from the normal .NET routines. You could check for a few things manually:

- Try parsing the number as a decimal. If that works, but parsing as an integer doesn't, then it's either out of the range of the integer, or it's not an integer.
- Look for non-decimal, non +/-, non-decimal-point characters
- Check whether it's an empty string

You haven't said what you're trying to parse (integer, double etc) or what options you want (allow hex, thousands separators etc) which makes it harder to give a good list of things to check.

Comment: Focus isnt set on something particular, so your answer is pretty good :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The TryParse() method is there when you want to be shielded from any exceptions.

If you want to see the exceptions then why not use the standard Parse() method in a try/catch block which will allow you to view any FormatExceptions etc thrown? 
As expected, with exception handling, this could impact performance however if the Parse() is expected to succeed then this should be tolerable.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the regular Parse method instead?